# git clone fatal: pack has bad object at offset N: unknown object type 0

Tags: git, tfs, git-clone

We have a project on TFS git, it works fine on my PC(push,pull), but when trying to clone from another PC we get error:

> Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with
>   a fatal error. pack has bad object at offset 78771578: unknown object
>   type 0 index-pack failed

Did anyone faced with this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I tried to download project folders as zip. I can download all folders but **'/Web/MyProjectName.Web/Views'** folder is giving error and not downloading. Here is error details:

> TF401031: The Git pack entry header is invalid.Hide details
>   TFS.WebApi.Exception: TF401031: The Git pack entry header is invalid.
>   at k
>   (MyProjectUrl/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=ITI0eYHCCehqqjk6JTyPaR5R793ETLoY2_Lqz191Pyo1:64:375)
>   at
>   MyProjectUrl/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=ITI0eYHCCehqqjk6JTyPaR5R793ETLoY2_Lqz191Pyo1:64:2955
>   at d
>   (MyProjectUrl/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=ITI0eYHCCehqqjk6JTyPaR5R793ETLoY2_Lqz191Pyo1:64:635)
>   at
>   MyProjectUrl/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=ITI0eYHCCehqqjk6JTyPaR5R793ETLoY2_Lqz191Pyo1:64:2888
>   at l (MyProjectUrl/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:8122) at
>   MyProjectUrl/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:8348 at t.when
>   (MyProjectUrl/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:3780) at t.u.promiseDispatch
>   (MyProjectUrl/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:2824) at
>   MyProjectUrl/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:1649 at MessagePort.t
>   (MyProjectUrl/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:5773)

Comment: have you tried to  clone that repo on your own machine?

Comment: You can run `git fsck` against a repository to verify its integrity.

Comment: That would indicate that there was a problem transmitting the pack file and it became corrupt.  Does this fail consistently?  Is the offset consistently the same?  Are they on the same network, or is there a different connection to the server?  Is the other PC using a proxy?

Comment: @EdwardThomson yes it fails consistently, offset consistently the same. We tried on the same network, and on different networks, and there is no proxy

Comment: @DarjanBogdan I will try on my own maschine and will post result

Comment: What version of Git are you using on the machine that works?  And the one that doesn't?

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev Any update on this issue, have you figured it out?

Comment: @EdwardThomson git version 2.17.0.windows.1 on both maschines

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT I haven't figured out yet, problem is existing

Comment: I have this problem and cloning does nothing.

Comment: Me too with a 2.2GB repo.